# Can we access a Kusama blocknumber from a parachain?

Tags: parachain, parachain-system

We are designing a parachain pallet. Part of it delays a call until a certain block number. Kusama has more consistent blocktimes than our newly born parachain. Is there a way we can access the block number of Kusama?

Comment: This may answer your question: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/3646/from-a-parachain-how-to-get-the-current-relay-chain-block-number