# From a parachain, how to get the current relay chain block number?

Tags: parachain, relay-chain, blocknumber

From a parachain, how to get the current relay chain block number?

I would like to write a hook using the relay chain block as a trigger.

Answer (score 8):

Great question!

You can include the following in your parachain's runtime:

```rust
use cumulus_pallet_parachain_system::RelaychainBlockNumberProvider;
```

Then, in the parachain's runtime, define the following in your pallet's config:

```rust
type RelayChainBlockNumber = RelaychainBlockNumberProvider<Runtime>;
```

In your pallet you will have to import `BlockNumberProvider`:

```rust
use sp_runtime::traits::BlockNumberProvider;
```

Define it in your pallet's config:

```rust
type RelayChainBlockNumber: BlockNumberProvider<BlockNumber = Self::BlockNumber>;
```

And, finally, you can get the relaychain's block number in your pallet:

```rust
let current_relaychain_block_number = T::RelayChainBlockNumber::current_block_number();
log::info!("The current relaychain block number is {:?}", current_relaychain_block_number);
```

Here is an example:

- https://github.com/brunopgalvao/cumulus-001/commit/033bebb2eeaa7e29fac7d7dc25558cc80e6d9b2f